# Script to start network connection when disconnected

Tags: linux, bash

Here is a command I run to connect from my Ubuntu Linux server to a windows share folder:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //ipaddress/xml /var/www/dir/pub/xml -o user=username,password=password
```

The windows server restarts when updates are applied but I wouldn't know when it is restart so I would like to create a bash script on my Ubuntu Linux server to detect the disconnection and re-establish the connection...

for starters I would go about this:

```
#/bin/bash

if[/var/www/dir/pub/xml/* == '']; then
    sudo mount -t cifs //ipaddress/xml /var/www/dir/pub/xml -o user=username,password=password
fi
```

I would add this to a cron job to schedule it to run at least five minutes...
I am not an expert at bash scripts but I would appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction... Thanks.

Comment: for me, disconnection automatically leads to reconnection when necessary, have you checked whether that happens for you?

Comment: hmmmm, checking logs and investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you are on the right track, except I would change the script just a little:

```
#/bin/bash

if [ "$(ls -1 /var/www/dir/pub/xml/* | wc -l)" = 0 ] ; then
    mount -t cifs //ipaddress/xml /var/www/dir/pub/xml -o user=username,password=password
fi

exit
```

I changed the if statement, so it checks for content in the xml folder, and took sudo away from the mount command, since this will cause a password request on execution. Now you place the script into the:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

file...

Comment: Let me know if you need advice on adding cron jobs.

Comment: Wow thanks! I would appreciate some advise on adding a cron job... I am doing some research myself but creating a cron job is new for me.  Thank you!

Comment: Sure, I will write a simple tutorial tomorrow morning. :-)

Comment: in my crontab -e file would my file look something like this if I would like it every 5 minutes for everyday? 05 * * * *  /var/www/dir/connect.sh

Comment: More like: 05,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /path-to-script

Comment: Remember to use $ sudo crontab -e - not just $ crontab -e 
This way the scheduler runs the script as root, not your logged in user which is important for the mount command in this case.